# Ruby CSV prevent appending header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

While I'm appending data to csv in a loop headers also getting appended in csv file, for example consider below query

```
10.times do 
   CSV.open("file_name", "ab", write_headers: true, headers: ["team", "points"]) do |csv|
     csv << ["SRH","20"]   
   end
end
```

Resulting CSV will have alternate headers and alternate values. 
How to prevent appending headers multiple times? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're opening the same csv file in every loop, do you definitely want to do that?

Comment: I don't mean I would append in loop, in runtime I would be appending to the existing file multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You are opening up your csv file and adding data in a loop. You want to open your file ones and then add any data in a loop.

```
CSV.open("file_name", "ab", write_headers: true, headers: ["team", "points"]) do |csv|
   10.times do 
     csv << ["SRH","20"]   
   end
end
```

The output is:

```
team,points
SRH,20
SRH,20
SRH,20
SRH,20
SRH,20
SRH,20
SRH,20
SRH,20
SRH,20
SRH,20
```